# How to drop all columns under highest level of hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

After using a 'groupby' function on a data frame, I have a new data frame with a multilevel hierarchy of columns. One of the top level (e.g. index=0) columns is named 'Total', with a variable number of second level columns beneath it (index=1). I have found solutions to dropping one or more second level columns at a time using indexing where each column name is specified, but my script will generate numerous and a variable number of columns under the top level, depending on my data source. I would like to just point to the top level column named 'Total', and delete ALL of the columns that fall under it in the hierarchy without necessarily having to know the potential names of the second level columns.

I have experimented with dropping a single column, but cannot find anything online that allows me to drop all columns. Most examples specify you must point to the index of the column you want to drop, but my code can generate lots of second level columns depending on the data source (e.g. the number and names of secondary columns may not be known in advance).

An example of dropping a single second level (index=1) column:

`df.drop('c', axis=1, level=1)`

I could find no code examples of getting rid of the secondary columns as a group.

My data frame looks like this, and I want to drop all the columns under "Total". The number of columns generated by the code can be large, so it is not possible to know in advance how many and what their names are. It

```
                     Total  Total   perCent        perCent
Antibiotic         AMPICI   BENZYL    AMPICI    BENZYL
Organism                
Enterococcus avium  1   1   0.0 (0/1)   0.0 (0/1)
Enterococcus cassel 1   1   100.0 (1/1) 100.0 (1/1)
Enterococcus faecalis   46  45  95.7 (44/46)    95.6 (43/45)
Enterococcus faecalis   2   2   100.0 (2/2) 100.0 (2/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for `DataFrame.droplevel()` (https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df.droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
```

However, this will result in duplicate column names, which is probably not desirable. Instead, you might want to flatten the column MultiIndex using values from both levels:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to convert the MultiIndex to a mere dataframe and identify the numeric position of the columns to keep. Then it is easy to drop the unwanted columns:

```
ix = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns).reset_index()

result = df.iloc[:, ix[ix['level_0']!='Total'].index]
```

With your sample data, it should give:

```
                               perCent              
              Antibiotic        AMPICI        BENZYL
                Organism                            
0     Enterococcus avium     0.0 (0/1)     0.0 (0/1)
1    Enterococcus cassel   100.0 (1/1)   100.0 (1/1)
2  Enterococcus faecalis  95.7 (44/46)  95.6 (43/45)
3  Enterococcus faecalis   100.0 (2/2)   100.0 (2/2)
```

Comment: This last solution worked exactly as expected. I have removed all columns under 'Total'. Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: @Wilbur60: If you no longer need help on that question, do not forget to accept one of the answers.